# How to make permutation matrix for two lists of str, Python3

Tags: string, python-3.x, permutation

I have two lists.

```
a_num = [1, 3, 2, 4]
b_num = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I want to find a permutation matrix to convert `a` to `b`. Mathematically, a permutation matrix is a square matrix, whose elements are either 1 or 0. It can change the sequence of elements in a vector, by multiplying it.
In this particular example, the permutation matrix is:

```
p = [[1,0,0,0],
     [0,0,1,0],
     [0,1,0,0],
     [0,0,0,1]]
# check whether p is correct.
b_num == np.dot(np.array(p), np.array(a_num).reshape(4,1))
```

Could you please show me how to make that matrix `p`? In my real application, there can be tens of elements in the lists with arbitrary sequence. And the two lists always contain `str` instead of `int`.
And how to make `p` when the `a` and `b` are lists of `str`?

```
a_str = ['c1', 'c2', 's1', 's2']
b_str = ['c1', 's1', 'c2', 's2']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pure Python you can do:

```
a_str = ['c1', 'c2', 's1', 's2']
b_str = ['c1', 's1', 'c2', 's2']

from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(lambda: [0, []])
for i, x in enumerate(b_str):  # collect indexes of target chars
    dd[x][1].append(i)

matrix = [[0]*len(a_str) for x in b_str]

for i, a in enumerate(a_str):
    # set cell at row (src index) and col (next tgt index) to 1
    matrix[i][dd[a][1][dd[a][0]]] = 1  
    # increment index for looking up next tgt index
    dd[a][0] += 1

matrix
# [[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

This assumes that `a_str` and `b_str` are in fact respective permutations.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: works only with numbers.

For arrays with the same length using `NumPy`:

```
import numpy as np

a_num = [1, 3, 2, 4]
b_num = [4, 2, 3, 1]
a = np.array(a_num)
b = np.array(b_num)
len_v = len(a)  # = len(b)

A = np.zeros((len_v, len_v))
A[np.argsort(a), np.arange(len_v)] = 1

B = np.zeros((len_v, len_v))
B[np.argsort(b), np.arange(len_v)] = 1

np.dot(np.linalg.inv(B), np.dot(A, a))  # array([4., 2., 3., 1.])
```