# How to change elements positions in a list

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list

I have a permutation matrix, which is a square matrix and the elements are either 1 or 0.

```
p = [[1, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 0],
     [0, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

If I multiply `p` to a list of `int`, the positions of elements in the list will be changed. For example

```
a_num = [1, 3, 2, 4]
np.dot(np.array(p), np.array(a_num).reshape(4,1))
# results is [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Now I want to changes a list of `str`:

```
a_str = ['c1', 'c3', 'c2', 'c4']
```

to

```
['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']
```

Do you know how to achieve it with matrix `p`? Please note that my real application can have tens of elements in the list.

For your information. There is a post about
[How to generate permutation matrix based on two lists of str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53079668/how-to-make-permutation-matrix-for-two-lists-of-str-python3/53080207#53080207)

Comment: Are they all in `'c1..n'` format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without numpy by leveraging enumerate in a list comprehension:

```
p = [[1, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 0],
     [0, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 1]]

a_str = ['c1', 'c3', 'c2', 'c4']

b_str = [a_str[idx] for row in p for idx,i in enumerate(row) if i == 1]

print(b_str)
```

Output:

```
 ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']
```

It takes each inner list of `p` and uses the element of `a_str` at the `idx` of that inner list that is one, creating a new list by that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `numpy.take`:

```
>>> numpy.take(numpy.array(a_str), numpy.array(a_num)-1)
array(['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'], dtype='|S2')
```